# Should ("...") be used in templates?

Tags: lit-element, lit-html

In `lit-element` @ Templates @ Bind properties to child elements (documentation) for

- Attribute: `<p id="${...}"></p>`
- Boolean attribute: `?checked="${...}"`
- Property: `.value="${...}"`
- Event handler: `@event="${...}"`

  a pair of `"` is always used.

On the contrary, in `lit-html` @ Writing templates (documentation) a pair of `"` is never used, eg:

- Attribute: `<p id=${...}></p>`
- Boolean attribute: `?checked=${...}`
- Property: `.value=${...}`
- Event handler: `@event=${...}`

Is there any reason for that? Is any style more preferable than the other?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real difference, both are valid syntax and you should just use the style that suits you the best